# Create columns in pandas dataframe based on values in a particular column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe:

| Name | Subject |
| --- | --- |
| Joe | Maths |
| Joe | Physics |
| Alba | Physics |
| Alba | Biology |
| Alba | Chemistry |
| George | Linguistics |

I want to convert it into the following:

| Name | Subject1 | Subject2 | Subject3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | Maths | Physics | - |
| Alba | Physics | Biology | Chemistry |
| George | Lingusitcs | - | - |

Answer (score 0):

Group the rows by name and convert the second column first into a list and then into a series. A more efficient solution may be possible.

```
df.groupby('Name')['Subject'].apply(list).apply(pd.Series).fillna('-')
#                  0        1          2
#Name                                   
#Alba        Physics  Biology  Chemistry
#George  Linguistics        -          -
#Joe           Maths  Physics          -
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use a [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) in conjunction with [`groupby cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), then collapse the MultiIndex:

```
new_df = df.set_index([
    'Name',
    df.groupby('Name').cumcount() + 1  # enumerate rows per name
]).unstack(
    fill_value='-'  # Fill Missing Values with '-'
)
# Collapse MultiIndex
new_df.columns = new_df.columns.map(lambda t: ''.join(map(str, t)))
# Restore Range Index
new_df = new_df.reset_index()
```

Or with [`pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) to keep as a chain:

```
new_df = df.set_index([
    'Name',
    df.groupby('Name').cumcount() + 1  # enumerate rows per name
]).unstack(
    fill_value='-'  # Fill Missing Values with '-'
).pipe(lambda d: d.set_axis(
    # Collapse MultiIndex
    d.columns.map(lambda t: ''.join(map(str, t))),
    axis=1
)).reset_index()  # Restore Name Column
```

`new_df`:

```
     Name     Subject1 Subject2   Subject3
0     Joe        Maths  Physics          -
1    Alba      Physics  Biology  Chemistry
2  George  Linguistics        -          -
```

---

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['Joe', 'Joe', 'Alba', 'Alba', 'Alba', 'George'],
    'Subject': ['Maths', 'Physics', 'Physics', 'Biology', 'Chemistry',
                'Linguistics']
})
```